# Compute the flux of the vector field $\vec{F}$ through the surface S

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\vec{F}:U ⊆ R
^3 → R
^3$ be the vector field

$(x/
(x
^2 + y
^2 + z
^2
)
^{3/2}
,
y/
(x
^2 + y^
2 + z^
2
)
^{3/2}
,
z/
(x^
2 + y^
2 + z^
2
)
^{3/2})
$

where U is $R
^3$ \ (0, 0, 0). Compute the flux of the vector field $\vec{F}$ through the surface S given
by taking the sphere of radius 12345 centered at the origin, chopping off a small section from
the top of the sphere, and replacing the chopped-off section with a flat disk, so that S remains
closed.

Assume S is oriented with an outward-pointing normal.

I understand how to compute the flux of the vector field, but I am confused on how I can compute it through the surface S. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Gauss’s divergence theorem to do this problem. Note that the vector field in spherical coordinates is $F=\frac{1}{r^2}\hat{r}$. It’s divergence is zero in the region (Call that volume V) between the flat portion (disk D)  and spherical cap C you just cut off. Let the remaining portion of the spherical surface be R.

Since the volume integral of the divergence over V is zero, by the divergence theorem, the flux outward through the flat portion is the same as the flux outward through the spherical cap.

Divergence theorem says $$\int_V \operatorname{div} F = 0 = \int_C F \cdot \hat{n} - \int_D F \cdot \hat{n}$$

Here I have chosen the unit normal vectors on both surfaces to be the ones pointing away from the origin. Hence the negative sign.  So

$$  \int_C F \cdot \hat{n} = \int_D F \cdot \hat{n}$$  $$
So the flux through S is the same as the flux through the whole sphere.

$$  \int_S F \cdot \hat{n} = \int_{R+D} F \cdot \hat{n} = \int_{R+C} F \cdot \hat{n} = \int_{\mbox{sphere}} F \cdot \hat{n} = \frac{1}{R^2} A$$ where A is the area of the sphere of the given radius R.

Comment: Okay I understand your explanation, but I don't get how to solve it. Can you please show the computation? Thanks

Comment: @ConnorBrown which computation? The flux through the whole sphere or the application of Guass’s theorem over V?

Comment: Both, if possible!

Comment: Okay thanks. So now I would just plug in 12345 for R and pi$12345^2$ for A and solve?

Comment: @ConnorBrown right, except...the surface area of a sphere is not πr ²... there is a factor of 4, no?

Comment: How did you account for the 3/2 exponent in the vector field by the way?

Comment: @ConnorBrown It is (r ² )^(3/2) which is r ³, no? Your vector field is $\frac{\bar{r}}{r^3}=\frac{r}{r^3}\hat{r}=\frac{1}{r^2}\hat{r}$